# compare variables using IF statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, click, compare

I have two buttons named sqr1 and sqr2, what i wanted is when both buttons are clicked .i.e if the IF condition satisfies it should alert message but it is showing alert even if any one button is clicked. I wanted it when both buttons are clicked.

new1.html

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function saveVal() {
    var squ1 = document.getElementById("sq1").value;
    localStorage.setItem("sq1", squ1);
    squ1 = localStorage.getItem("sq1");

    var squ2 = document.getElementById("sq2").value;
    localStorage.setItem("sq2", squ2);
    squ2 = localStorage.getItem("sq2");
</script>
<html>
<body>
<form method="get" action="new2.html">

<input type="number" id="sq1" name="sqrone"   placeholder=" Enter Number" class="tictac"  />

<input type="number" id="sq2" name="sqrtwo"   placeholder=" Enter Number" class="tictac"  />

<input type="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="saveVal()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

new2.html

```
<script>
    var sqr1
    var sqr2

var square1 = document.getElementById("sq1");
    square1.value = localStorage.getItem("sq1");

    var square2 = document.getElementById("sq2");
    square2.value = localStorage.getItem("sq2");

    var sqval1 = document.write(square1.value);
    var sqval2 = document.write(square2.value);

    function check{
    if((sqr1 ==  sqval1)  && (sqr2 ==  sqval2)  ) 
      {
          alert('you win!')
      }
}
</script>
<html>
<body>
<INPUT TYPE="button" id="sq1" NAME="sqr1"  class="tictac"    onClick=" check() ">

<INPUT TYPE="button" id="sq2" NAME="sqr2"  class="tictac"   onClick="check() ">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The variables you are comparing are completely unrelated to clicking anything.

Comment: How does sqr1 get set? How does sqr2 get set? What values do all the variables have during comparison? What did you find when you used your debugger? You need to show us some sort of effort other than "I wrote this and it doesn't work".

Comment: I have some value in sqval1 and another sqval2, and as sqr1 and sqr2 are  names of buttons when sqr1 has value of sqval1 and sqr2 has value of sqval2 it should give message.

Comment: @takendarkk i have edited code can you have a look

Comment: I still don't see where you give the sqr1 and sqr2 variables a value.

Comment: If you want to determine when each button has been clicked, then you need to *do something different* depending on which button was clicked.

Comment: @takendarkk Or can i do like when these two buttons are clicked it should alert message if so how can i do it.

Comment: You will not answer the most basic questions I have asked. I am not going to provide any more assistance until you do so. Show where those two vars get values.

Comment: @takendarkk I get those values from another HTML page from a form like this `var squ1 = document.getElementById("sq1").value;
    localStorage.setItem("sq1", squ1);
    squ1 = localStorage.getItem("sq1");
 
 var squ2 = document.getElementById("sq2").value;
    localStorage.setItem("sq2", squ2);
    squ2 = localStorage.getItem("sq2");`

Comment: You need to post that code in your question. Show how it is related to the code you already posted. Then you can answer the next question I asked which is what are the values of all the variables right before the comparison is performed?

Comment: @takendarkk here is what you asked for i have edited.

Comment: That code has `squ1` not `sqr1`. Is all of this caused by a typo? Also, why are you trying to use implicit variables from a whole separate file? You should get the values where you need them.

Comment: And you STILL haven't told us what the values of each variable are right before the comparison is performed.

Comment: @takendarkk assume that `document.write(square1.value);` returns value 1 and is stored in sqval1 and like wise for sqval2 and assume that sqr1 has value 1 and sqr2 has value 2 and now should make the comparision.

Comment: This is computer code so I will not assume anything - there's no need. Don't assume what the values are, use your debugger and KNOW what they are. Then tell us what those values are. I am done responding until you do this.

Comment: @takendarkk thank you so much for your assistance. my problem is i think i am unable to express the problem and i shall work it and will get back to you if needed thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to do, but this will show an alert only if both buttons have been pressed:

HTML

```
<button id="button1" type="button" onclick="button1check()">button1</button>
<button id="button2" type="button" onclick="button2check()">button2</button>
```

JS

```
button1clicked = 0;
button2clicked = 0;

function button1check() {
  button1clicked = 1;

  if (button1clicked == 1 && button2clicked == 1) {
    alert('you win!');
    button1clicked = 0;
    button2clicked = 0;
  }
}


function button2check() {
  button2clicked = 1;

  if (button1clicked == 1 && button2clicked == 1) {
    alert('you win!');
    button1clicked = 0;
    button2clicked = 0;
  }
}
```